# SQL Create Unique Value Flag

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

There are lots of questions/answers about selecting unique values in a MySQL query but I haven't seen any on creating a unique value flag.

I have a customer_ID that can appear more than once in a query output. I want to create a new column that flags whether the customer_ID is unique or not (0 or 1).

The output should look something like this:

```
ID     | Customer ID      | Unique_Flag
1      | 1234             | 1
2      | 2345             | 1
3      | 2345             | 0
4      | 5678             | 1
```

Please let me know if anybody needs clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to mark the first occurrence as unique, but not others.  So, let's join in the comparison value:

```
select t.*,
       (id = min_id) as is_first_occurrence
from t join
     (select customer_id, min(id) as min_id
      from t
      group by customer_id
     ) tt
     on t.customer_id = tt.customer_id;
```

For most people, a "unique" flag would mean that the overall count is "1", not that this is merely the first appearance.  If that is what you want, then you can use similar logic:

```
select t.*,
       (id = min_id) as is_first_occurrence,
       (cnt = 1) as is_unique
from t join
     (select customer_id, min(id) as min_id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by customer_id
     ) tt
     on t.customer_id = tt.customer_id;
```

And, in MySQL 8+, you would use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by id) = 1) as is_first_occurrence,
       (count(*) over (partition by customer_id) = 1) as is_unique
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
select id,a.customerid, case when cnt=1 then 1 else 0 end as Unique_Flag
from tablename a 
left join 
(select customerid, count(*) as cnt from tablename
group by customerid
)b on a.customerid=b.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sample table example]You can use lead function as given below to get the required output.

`SELECT ID, CUSTOMER_ID,
CASE
    WHEN CUSTOMER_ID != CUSTOMER_ID_NEXT THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS UNIQUE_FLAG FROM
(SELECT ID, CUSTOMER_ID,LEAD(CUSTOMER_ID, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) AS CUSTOMER_ID_NEXT FROM TABLE)T`